# Would an Option or Optional type (Option<T>) make sense in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, pattern-matching, option-type

Languages like Haskell, Rust, among others, offer a [`Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Maybe) or [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) type. Even in Java, there is a [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Optional.html) type nowadays.

For simplicity, I will call this type an 'Option type' in the remaining question. '*Optional* type' is apparently often used to describe situations where providing type annotations is optional.

I am curious about the following: does an Option type make sense in a language like TypeScript? The advantages of the Option type are quite convincing in other languages and I find myself missing the type when programming in TypeScript.

Basically, the type system forces you to explicitly unwrap any value that may be inside an Option value. Yes, TypeScript's strict null-checking can also accomplish that, however, working with the Option type offers you an (in my opinion) much nicer way to handle potential `None` values by providing `map(f: T -> U): Option<U>` and `mapOr(f: T -> U, or: U): Option<U>` methods, etc.

For instance, I would like something like the following code to work:

```
interface Foo {
    member: Option<string>
}
const opt: Option<Foo> = // ... some initialization
const memberLength: number = opt
    .map(x => x.member) // None if x is None, else Some(...)
    .map(x => x.length) // None if x.member is None, else Some(x.length)
    .unwrapOrElse(() => 0);
```

This is, of course a very simple example, where using an Option type is a bit over-engineered. It should give a basic idea, though.

I currently don't see a reason why this would be a bad idea, but no one seems to have implemented it, as far as I can tell. Would this have a serious performance impact? Or are there any other issues I can't see that make this non-viable?

**Note:** I am not (mainly) asking for how to implement this (although that is also an interesting topic -- but I have ideas for that). My main concern is finding out why no one seems to be using something like this yet.

Comment: While it's a nice discussion subject the discussions are going to be opinion based and as such SO is not the forum to hold such a conversation. :)

Comment: the function `map` you mentioned can be defined like this : `map<T,U>(val: T|null|undefined,f : T -> U): U|null|undefined` and implementation is easy, the case is similar for `mapOr` , you can even alias `T|null|undefined` as `Option<T>` I think

Comment: the reason those languages have these types is because they don't have union types but tagged unions(yes these two are different)

Comment: @niceman I agree this would be easy to implement (even though I am not sure I agree with the implementation you provide) but I was wondering why nobody seems to have done this

Comment: @toskv I could take this elsewhere, of course, sorry. But of course it is going to be opinion-based, I don't think this question stands out from others in that respect.

Comment: @niceman do I understand correctly that you suggest union types are an appropriate replacement of an Option type? I don't think so. Sure, I can declare a value as `Foo | undefined` but that doesn't allow me to write in a fluent API on top of it. If `x` is of type `Foo | undefined` it may be `undefined` and thus `x.bar()` will fail miserably.

Comment: @anty I don't see how you're missing out on anything in TypeScript, other than maybe unboxing syntax in match expressions? Can you post an example of code you would like to work?

Comment: I was missing it so I made my own lib for it (and a few others): https://github.com/bgrieder/MM   (MIT)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091601/1623521

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT 2023**

use: [effect](https://github.com/Effect-TS/effect)

**EDIT 2019**

Check [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts)

**Original Answer**

I was missing it coming from Scala (and some Haskell) so I made my own lib for it (and a couple others): [MM](http://github.com/bgrieder/MM) (MIT license)

Feel free to hack, fork etc...; it is MIT licensed

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091601/1623521

Answer (score 1):

[sniptt/monads](https://github.com/sniptt-official/monads) is a simple library that adds rust-style `Option` and `Result` types to typescript. I've tried out a lot of these and this was the simplest to use.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77091601/1623521