# What is the advantage of using Option instead of typescript's optional `?` operator?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, option-type, fp-ts

I am getting started with `fp-ts` lib and was wondering what is the advantage of using Option type over typescript's default notion of optional values represented by question mark `?` operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript tells you whether or not you have the value or not with the question mark. However, often you'll want to perform some sort of computation on them and this is when the Option type from fp-ts shines.

For example, let's say we have two items in a shop and they optionally have prices and we want to write a function to get the price of both of them otherwise we return some value that represents "not for sale". First we'll see how we would do this in vanilla typescript

```
type ShopItem = {
    price?:number
}
const getPrice = (item1: ShopItem, item2: ShopItem):number | null => {
    const price1 = item1.price;
    const price2 = item2.price;

    if (price1 && price2) {
        return price1 + price2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This has a few problems. First, there's a bug in there because if the price was 0, then the item should be for sale but instead our falsey check would short circuit out and return null. Secondly, it doesn't scale very well. If we wanted to add multiple ShopItems or even other types of items with optional values, we'll need to keep checking whether or not those values were null.

Now let's compare this to the fp-ts example
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-wu-pffe3

```
import { some, none, ap, Option } from "fp-ts/lib/Option";
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable'

type ShopItem = {
    price:Option<number> //this type will either be a Some<number> or None
}
const getPrice = (item1: ShopItem, item2: ShopItem): Option<number> =>
  pipe( 
   some((a:number) => (b:number) => a + b), 
   ap(item1.price),
   ap(item2.price)
  );
```

The way this works is that we get the item1 price and the item2 price and we feed it into the addition function inside the some. Notice how there aren't any null checks as this has been abstracted away into our None type.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been possible though to get all these benefits by defining all these functions (map, ap) on top of the typescript optional `type Option<T> = T | undefined`?

Comment: hmm that might be a bit confusing if the T type includes undefined. By introducing a new type `None` we avoid that conflict.

Comment: I would say since `X | undefined` is the typescript variant of an optional (including ? notation) if `T` includes `undefined` it would be equivalent to `O.Option<O.Option<MyType>>`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @derp's points, but his code snippet is not the best. First, because it's quite difficult to wrap your head around the weird `pipe()` API, and second, because fp-ts is actually a deprecated library.

More info:

- fp-ts lib's documentation actually lacks any decent example of how to use Option types.
- If you manage to wrap your head around the shitty examples, you'll see there's no decent pattern-matching approach (more info: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts-contrib/issues/63 ).
- Turns out `fp-ts` lib is actually kinda old (they already closed the above pattern-matching github issue without a solution been provided).
- The author of `fp-ts` himself has stopped working on it, and is now working on a different lib: https://github.com/Effect-TS/effect ([more info](https://dev.to/effect-ts/a-bright-future-for-effect-455m))
- The best documentation samples for Option types for this lib above (including pattern matching) can be found here: https://www.effect.website/docs/data-types/option

(PS: I had written this answer in [Would an Option or Optional type (Option<T>) make sense in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266974/would-an-option-or-optional-type-optiont-make-sense-in-typescript/) but it got deleted because "it should be a comment of the most upvoted answer".)